# Xamarin.Android Problem while navigating between pages

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, httpclient, multipartform-data

I have a bug in my cross-platform app.
I have a page with a list of document (folders) and, when i click in one of them, i have some buttons to add some photos (file into the document folder) and send them to an url.
So, the execution flow is the follow:

DocumentList -> DocumentEditor -> AddPhotos

In DocumentEditor i have, as said before, the possibility to send the document (and related photos) to an url through a client.postAsync(String Url, MultipartFormDataContent). I haven't any problem during this operation, but when i press the back button in the navigation bar.

I come back in the prev page (DocumentList), but the title is cutted and, if i want to select another document, it opens a black DocumentEditor Page.

If i don't send the document, i haven't any problem with back button, so, it's definitely a problem with client.postAsync.

Any ideas?

Some pic:

DocumentList before postAsync:

[image]

DocumentEditor before postAsync:

[image]

DocumentList after postAsync and back button pressed (notice the title):

[image]

DocumentEditor after selected a document in prev image:

[image]

Some codes:

Click Handler in DocumentList:

```
private async void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Grid Cell = ((Grid)sender);
        String DirName = Cell.FindByName<Label>("DirName").Text;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new DocumentEditor(DirName, Type));
    }
```

SendDocument Button Handler:

```
private async void InviaDocumento_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        bool response await DisplayAlert("Invio", "Vuoi davvero inviare il documento?", "Si", "No");

        if (response)
        {
            String url = some codes...
            ...
            MultipartFormDataContent multiContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            ...SomeCodes to populate multiContent...
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);

            HttpResponseMessage response2 = await client.PostAsync(url, multiContent);
            if (response2.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("Upload", "Upload completato con successo!", "Ok");
                    //await Navigation.PopToRootAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    string error = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    await DisplayAlert("Errore", "Si è verificato un errore durante l'upload: " + error, "Ok");
                }
         }
  }
```

Edit:

On ios it works well, and, on android, this problem persists even with a button that executes Navigation.PopAsync()

Comment: What about the ios platform? Will the code work well on ios platform? If you call `Navigation.PopAsycn()` to go back to the 'DocumentList' page using a `Button`, will it work fine?

Comment: @JarvanZhang-MSFT Yes, on ios it works well :)! I'll edit my question with this detail. About the button, nope, it doesn't

Comment: I don't know why "client.PostAsync" is so problematic on Android

Comment: Did you try with `ConfigureAwait(true)` ? On *PostAsync* and maybe on *DisplayAlert*

Comment: @FabriceT yeah, the problem persists

Comment: Try using a simple page(which just has a button) to navigate to the 'DocumentEditor' page, then send a document to go back to the simple page to check if it will work.

Comment: @JarvanZhang-MSFT i've tried what you have suggested me, but the problem is still here :/...i return to the simple page (that has cutted title) and, when i click on the button, a black screen appears

Comment: How are you setting the page title ? In Xaml or in the constructor, in Page_Appearing event or from a model ? As workaround you could change how or when you set the page title

Comment: @FabriceT in the constructor of .cs...but the page title is a minor problem, compared to the impossibility to navigate between pages

Comment: My idea is that something is cleaned from memory when you send `PostAsync` ... try another approach, find a way to force the page context to refresh, maybe a clone of your model  ... or try to use **ICommand** instead of events ... For eg. the gesturecognizer, use its **Command**

Comment: @FabriceT Sorry for the delay, i was writing this issue on github (https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12739)...i will try your idea tomorrow, thanks

Comment: Hi, the link seems to be invalid. Please check that.

Comment: @Jarvan Zhang - MSFT https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/12739

Comment: Thanks for sharing the topic url. The sample link your provided on the topic seems also not to be correct.

Comment: @JarvanZhang-MSFT i have some serious problem with links these days :D! Check my new comment on Github or use this link -> https://github.com/feduss/SampleProblem12739_

Comment: I tested the sample on my side and faced the same problem as you desribed. Please wait for the response from the product team.

Comment: @JarvanZhang-MSFT yes :)! thanks both guys :)!

Comment: @JarvanZhang-MSFT after 3 months, the bug is still here :(